# Linq - get max of string that ends with an integer

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get the max of a string column such as - a1 a2 a3 ...

But when the max number is 10 or above - the linq returns a9 as the max. Why?

How do I solve this?

The code-

```
from d in db.Documents.OrderByDescending(d => d.Number)
Where (.....)
Select d.Number)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `1 < 9` ==> `a10 < a9` when comparing strings.
What is the format of the input?

Comment: The input is string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant do with normal linq, if you want to compare with alphanumeric values, you should do something like this,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> vals = new List<string>();
            vals.Add("a1");
            vals.Add("a11");
            vals.Add("a41");
            vals.Add("a13");
            vals.Add("a12");
            vals.Add("a9");
            var result = vals.OrderByDescending(x => orderNumbers(x));
        }
        public static string orderNumbers(string input)
        {
            return Regex.Replace(input, "[0-9]+", match => match.Value.PadLeft(10, '0'));
        }
```

Comment: did it help to solve your issue??

Comment: There's a problem: it throws an exception: "notsupportedexception". The code works fine with your example, but with mine it doesn't.  Var result= documents.OrderByDecending(x => ordernumbers(x)).where(x.id == user.id).max();

Comment: probably you need to cast

Comment: Cast to string?

Comment: I tried casting to string (.ToString()) - doesn't work... Same exception. Tried to .ToList() and got the same exception as well.

Comment: No, and I cant download anything from the internet... We have here like an inner web

Comment: ok, then cant help much bro

Comment: What you can do `var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList()` than `db.Documents.Select(d=>d.Number).ToList().Select(doc => new
            {
                EndsWith = numbers.FirstOrDefault(number => doc.EndsWith(number.ToString())),
                Document = doc
            }).OrderBy(orderedDoc => orderedDoc.EndsWith).Select(orderedDoc => orderedDoc.Document).ToList();`

Comment: Will try this in two days and will let you know. Thank you.

Comment: @Haksu it gave me all the numbers that there are in the db of the documents....

Comment: You have to add .Where to your query `db.Documents.Where(d=>d.Property==Someth‌​ing).Select(d=>d.Number).ToList()` also if you're going to use more than 10 you can do  `Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Reverse().ToList()` so it matches first bigger number than smaller like 11 and 1

Comment: Thank you so much!! It works now! How can I mark your comment as the solution?